# Bootstrap pull right buttons in list hanging out

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            userA <span class="label label-default">admin</span>
            <span class="pull-right button-group">
                <a href="/admin/userA" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

I would like to make the box bigger so the buttons fit within, whilst keeping the text/label vertically centered. Alternatively, moving the buttons up to be within the box would work. I'm using bootstrap 3.2. Any advice welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fix is simple, just add the clearfix to the element containing the floated items:

```
    <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
```

DEMO:http://jsbin.com/yazoj/1/edit

And

```
.list-group {line-height:30px}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tf50ohy5/1/)**

Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
      <!-- wrapped the text and label in a span -->
      <span style="position:absolute; top:30%;">userA <span class="label label-default">admin</span></span>
      <span class="pull-right button-group">
        <a href="/admin/userA" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You may want to move the inline style to css file.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Your code.. Yes there is a prob.
You can give an additional class first li element and then define padding for that.

**For example**
I have given an additional to first li "custom-class"

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item custom-class">
            userA <span class="label label-default">admin</span>
            <span class="pull-right button-group">
                <a href="/admin/userA" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now You can define the padding bottom to custom-class. You can increase the padding as you like.

```
 .custom-class{
     padding-bottom: 30px
}
```

Thanksss :)